# Why is my shirt cloth simulation clipping through my body mesh, and some parts still self-clipping despite enabling self-collisions?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation, collision

Creating clothes for my character with cloth simulation, and am having trouble with my body mesh clipping through my shirt when my character switches to a pose from his initial T-Pose, as well as having a bit of self-collision issues around the sleeve.
For troubleshooting, I have:

- Made sure the body mesh isn't colliding with the shirt mesh before simulating
- Started cloth sim with 20 frames of T-Pose before switching to other poses
- Turned on 'preserve volume' for armature modifier on both shirt and body mesh
- Enabled object collisions and self collisions for cloth sim, and turned down the distance for each
- Increased quality steps for both simulation and collisions
- Kept cloth mod at top of mod stack

What's strange is I copied the cloth sim preset from another project where everything worked fine and my shirt looked great, and I have since reference that project a few times but still cant find why my cloth is clipping through the body mesh here and not there.

My blend file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZjHkBeTlHYey3SNcuLlBLxzNpfpqckQB/view?usp=share_link). Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, apart from the cloth parameters that may need some tweakings (also apply some transforms), you should make sure that the weight is correct, see if I select the upper arm bone, the vertex group contains some vertices of the chest when it should not:

[image]